# unable to retrieve haml files in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have generated a new controller -

```
murtaza@murtaza-dev:~/workspace/rails/sim-sim$ rails g controller home index
          create  app/controllers/home_controller.rb
           route  get "home/index"
          invoke  haml
          create    app/views/home
          create    app/views/home/index.html.haml
          invoke  test_unit
          create    test/functional/home_controller_test.rb
          invoke  helper
          create    app/helpers/home_helper.rb
          invoke    test_unit
          create      test/unit/helpers/home_helper_test.rb
          invoke  assets
          invoke    coffee
          create      app/assets/javascripts/home.js.coffee
          invoke    scss
          create      app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.scss
```

However when I try to access it on localhost:3000/home/index, I get the below error on my webpage-

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template home/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
>   * "/home/murtaza/workspace/rails/sim-sim/app/views"

How do I remedy it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you should add "gem 'haml-rails'" into Gemfile development group

like this:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'haml-rails', :group => :development
```

Comment: I already have it in my gemfile. The haml file was created using the command - 'rails generate home index'.